# nav bar w/burger menu as open / close button

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

New to coding.

Having trouble with side nav bar with animated burger menu. Nav Bar opens and closes on on-click(of the animated burger), but it always pushes back to landing section. If I open nav bar and select section `#4`, app navigates to that section, but then when I click to close the nav bar it returns to the landing `(first) section`. In other words I can not close nav bar with out being sent back to landing `(first) section`.

Using basic JS function - `classList.toggle`

Nav part

```html
    <nav id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
        <a href="#section1">LANDING SEC 1</a>
        <a href="#section2">SECTION 2</a>
        <a href="#section3">SECTION 3</a>
        <a href="#section4">SECTION 4</a>
        <a href="#section5">SECTION 5</a>
      </nav>

     <a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

toggle part

```js
let sideBar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" )
  .addEventListener( "click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle( "activateAnimation" );
    sideBar.classList.toggle("openNav");

  });
```

Comment: Would it be possible to show an example of your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so we can assist you with your issue.

Comment: You can refer to this list and demo examples for your current situation: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Comment: Hey! I hope my snippet makes sense. <a> <span> is the animated burger, which is the button getting on click to open close. Technically opens/closes but then resends always back to landing.

Comment: What happens if you change the href for your `#nav-toggle` element to something like `#section2`? does it navigate to section 2?

Answer (score 0):

If the toggle button is triggering an undesired navigation event, the default behavior of the `#nav-toggle` link will need to be skipped. Using `event.preventDefault()` should work in this situation.

I've modified the code to pass in `event` to the `.addEventListener(` function, and then updating that event with `event.preventDefault()`

```
let sideBar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" )
  .addEventListener( "click", function(event) {
     this.classList.toggle( "activateAnimation" );
     sideBar.classList.toggle("openNav");
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and advise. Rohan the list is awesome, thanks! Turns out that I needed to add line of code to   preventDefault() stops browser from re-routing back to landing section. :)

Comment: prevnetDevault() was used on anchor tag!